# Cis-AB phenotype verification

Tags: hematology, blood-group

I know that my blood type is AB. I wanted to know if I am cis-AB since cis-AB seems to have a different approach in blood transfusion.

Is there a lab test that can verify is a person is under cis-AB blood group phenotype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,do you have any probe that your type is AB chimera transferase? I discovered it because my mother is type AB and my brother type O. I have 2 sisters and my self cis-AB (my younger sister and me rh-). If you carried a cis-AB allele and another allele was  B1, surely you got A and B type compatible, but if you carried an A1 or O1 allele, surely you got O type compatible or worse luck. For example, I have a very rare multi-blood genotypes (rh D- C-G-, K1-, M+N-S+s+ and another unknown antigen). Actually, it doesn't matter if you are cis or trans AB phenotype, the most important thing is to know if another 34 blood groups and 200 minor groups and 600 blood antigenes have a rare combination that makes blood incompatibily or autologous like Bombay phenotype or autotransfusion like me.
If you want to be sure about your genotype, you must make dna test with SNPs of 10 cis-AB alleles